# Change curl statement to axios

Tags: react-native

I'm quite new to curl and I don't know how to convert this to axios statement

```
curl https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/{user_id}/password.json \
  -X POST -d '{"password": "newpassword"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -v -u {email_address}:{password}
```

I can make this run in postman but I'm not sure to convert it to axios.

Below is my sample axios code but it I get a EOF error

```
const response = await axios.post(`https://${subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/${userId}/password.json`,
{
    "password": "12345678"
},
{
    auth: {
       username: `${email}/token`,
       password: ZENDESK_API_KEY
    }                    
})
```

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage

Comment: Did you check if the `subdomain` and `userId` values are present?

Comment: yes, it's not variables on my code but the values itself. I just modified it here in stack to not show the values

Comment: Did you try sending the request in postman?

Comment: Yes, in postman it is working. I think the problem is the format of the data in axios

Comment: is the EOF error in javascript or in the API response?

Comment: I think the error is in javascript. Should I enter content-type: application/json just to be sure it is being read as json?